# How to cut everything but the temperature from a weather api print Python

Tags: python

How would i go about cutting this output:

```
w = obs.get_weather()
w.get_temperature()                                # Get temperature in Kelvin

#output{'temp': 293.4, 'temp_kf': None, 'temp_max': 297.5, 'temp_min': 290.9}
```

To just this:

```
293.4
```

Comment: Save that result to a dictionary, let's say `dct`, then use `dct['temp']`

Answer (score 0):

You can get dictionary value by using my_dictionary[key]. For your code it will be:
`w.get_temperature()['temp']`